# By / at / in wholesale

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine you by some stuff in wholesaling basis. How would you say you bought them. I have listed a structure with separated prepositions. Please let me know which one sounds natural:

> - I purchased all this stuff **by** wholesale.
> - I purchased all this stuff **in** wholesale.
> - I purchased all this stuff **at** wholesale.

I searched on google, but I didn't find useful information.

Please let me know how a native speaker would say it if no one of my suggested sentences sounds natural here.

Comment: I would choose the third one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No preposition is needed, nor even customary. [Google Ngrams show](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buy%20wholesale%2C%20buy%20at%20wholesale%2C%20buy%20in%20wholesale%2C%20buy%20by%20wholesale&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuy%20wholesale%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuy%20at%20wholesale%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuy%20in%20wholesale%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuy%20by%20wholesale%3B%2Cc0) that **buy wholesale** is far more common than the others.

- *Buy by wholesale* is practically nonexistent.
- *Buy at wholesale* probably shows up as often as it does because one does say **buy at wholesale prices** or **buy at wholesale markets**.
- *Buy in wholesale* probably comes from **buy in wholesale quantities**.

So you could say:

> I purchased all this stuff at wholesale prices

but that carries the implication that you bought a smaller quantity than wholesalers typically do, though you were lucky enough to pay the wholesale price.

You could also say:

> I purchased all this stuff in wholesale quantities

but that emphasizes the large amount you bought rather than the lower price you paid for it.

For your sentence, though, leaving off any preposition probably the best fits your meaning. To cover both the price and the quantity at which you bought the items, you would simply say:

> I purchased all this stuff **wholesale**.